# Do pet parrots need vaccinations?

Tags: parrots, vaccination

I live in South Africa where I'm not aware of the necessity or vaccines for pet parrots. Do pet parrots require vaccinations anywhere else in the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only available avian vaccine is for avian polyomavirus (APV). APV is usually only a problem for hand-fed chicks. If chicks are parent-raised (or if they are shared-socialized, so that the parents and the human caretaker both feed the chicks), APV is rarely a problem, because antibodies are passed from the parents to the chicks during feedings. The vaccine itself can cause problems, and there is not a consensus among veterinarians about the wisdom of vaccinating for APV.

An excellent, up-to-date discussion by Dr. Susan Orosz of APV vaccination can be found at: https://lafeber.com/pet-birds/vaccines-pet-birds/